# How do I deal with localStorage in jest tests?

Tags: jestjs

I keep getting "localStorage is not defined" in Jest tests which makes sense but what are my options? Hitting brick walls.

Comment: This is what dependency injection is for

Comment: For future readers, this question is now outdated, as localStorage is natively supported. related: [where does jest localstorage implementation come from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873429/where-does-jest-localstorage-implementation-come-from).

Answer (score 204):

Great solution from [@chiedo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2015685/chiedo)

However, we use ES2015 syntax and I felt it was a little cleaner to write it this way.

```js
class LocalStorageMock {
  constructor() {
    this.store = {};
  }

  clear() {
    this.store = {};
  }

  getItem(key) {
    return this.store[key] || null;
  }

  setItem(key, value) {
    this.store[key] = String(value);
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    delete this.store[key];
  }
}

global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock;
```

Comment: Should probably do `value + ''` in the setter to handle null and undefined values correctly

Comment: I think that latest jest was just using that `|| null` that's why my test was failing, because in my test I was using `not.toBeDefined()`. @Chiedo solution make it work again

Comment: I think this is technically a stub :) see here for the mocked version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests/54239779#answer-54239779

Comment: **Update 2021**:  For people using Jest@24 and above, localStorage is mocked automatically.

Comment: hi @NiketPathak, do you have a source for this? I couldn't find anything about it in the release notes for version 24 or the documentation.

Comment: I am using Jest@24 and it is not available. I had to mock per the solution. @NiketPathak

Comment: @NiketPathak I'm using Jest@27 and it's not mocked automatically :/

Comment: **Update 2022**:  Actually, I think @NiketPathak meant jest@22 and above, since [that version uses jsdom@11](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v22.0.0/packages/jest-environment-jsdom/package.json#L13) and [support for localStorage and sessionStorage was added on jsdom 11.12.0](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/master/Changelog.md#11120)

Comment: Nice, should use ?? instead of || so empty string is handled correctly.

Comment: This is not a mock, it's a fake.

Answer (score 151):

**Answer**:

Currently (Jul '22) localStorage can not be mocked or spied on by jest as you usually would, and as outlined in the create-react-app docs. This is due to changes made in jsdom. You can read about it in the [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6798) and [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2318) issue trackers.

As a workaround, you can spy on the prototype instead:

```js
// does not work:
jest.spyOn(localStorage, "setItem");
localStorage.setItem = jest.fn();

// either of these lines will work, different syntax that does the same thing:
jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem');
Storage.prototype.setItem = jest.fn();

// assertions as usual:
expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**A note on spying on the prototype**:

Spying on an instance gives you the ability to observe and mock behaviour for a specific object.

Spying on the prototype, on the other hand, will observe/manipulate every instance of that class all at once. Unless you have a special usecase, this is probably not what you want.

While in many cases when dealing with `localStorage`, using the prototype is acceptable, @onlywei pointed out an important caveat:

> This strategy will not allow you to differentiate between `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, as both are instances of `Storage` and inherit from the Storage prototype.

For implementations that deal with both concepts, you want to consider your specific situation and implications.

Comment: Actually it works for me just with the spyOn, no need to override setItem function
`jest.spyOn(window.localStorage.__proto__, 'setItem');`

Comment: Yes, I listed the two as alternatives, no need to do both.

Comment: i meant without the override of the setItem as well 

Comment: I don't think I understand. Can you clarify please?

Comment: The second line of « works: » (window.localStorage[...].setItem=jest.fn()) wasn’t necessary for me to make it work.

Comment: Ah yes. I was saying you can use either the first line, or the second line. They are alternatives that do the same thing. Whatever is your personal preference :)

Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: FWIW, eslint now says that obj.__proto__ is deprecated and its best to use Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) instead.  That also seems to work here.

Comment: This strategy will not allow you to differentiate between localStorage and sessionStorage, as both are instances of Storage and inherit from the Storage prototype.

Answer (score 142):

Figured it out with help from this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jestjs/9EPhuNWVYTg

Setup a file with the following contents:

```js
var localStorageMock = (function() {
  var store = {};
  return {
    getItem: function(key) {
      return store[key];
    },
    setItem: function(key, value) {
      store[key] = value.toString();
    },
    clear: function() {
      store = {};
    },
    removeItem: function(key) {
      delete store[key];
    }
  };
})();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: localStorageMock });
```

Then you add the following line to your package.json under your Jest configs

`"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile":"PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE",`

Comment: Apparently with one of the updates the name of this parameter changed and now it is called "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile"

Comment: `"setupFiles": [...]` works as well. With the array option, allows separating mocks into separate files. 

E.g.: `"setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/__mocks__/localStorageMock.js"]`

Comment: The return value of `getItem` differs slightly to what would be returned by a browser if the no data is set against a specific key. calling `getItem("foo")` when its not set will for example return `null` in a browser, but `undefined` by this mock - this was causing one of my tests to fail. Simple solution for me was to return `store[key] || null` in the `getItem` function

Comment: this doesn't work if you do something like `localStorage['test'] = '123'; localStorage.getItem('test')`

Comment: What is the IIFE for in this example? 
Any reason I can't just do this:
`Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
     value: {
        store: {},
        getItem: function(key) {
            return this.store[key] || null;
        },
        setItem: function(key, value) {
            this.store[key] = value.toString();
        },
        clear: function() {
            this.store = {};
        }
    }
});`

Comment: I am getting the following error - jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're using TS and get errors, you can give `store` a type annotation, i.e.

`const store: Record<string, any> = {};`

Answer (score 77):

If using create-react-app, there is a simpler and straightforward solution explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/running-tests.md#srcsetuptestsjs-1).

Create `src/setupTests.js` and put this in it :

```
const localStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn(),
  setItem: jest.fn(),
  clear: jest.fn()
};
global.localStorage = localStorageMock;
```

*Tom Mertz contribution in a comment below :*

You can then test that your localStorageMock's functions are used by doing something like

```
expect(localStorage.getItem).toBeCalledWith('token')
// or
expect(localStorage.getItem.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
```

inside of your tests if you wanted to make sure it was called. Check out https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Comment: Hi c4k! Could you please give an example how you would use that in your tests?

Comment: What do you mean ? You don't have to initialize anything in your tests, it just mocks automatically the `localStorage` you use in your code. (if you use `create-react-app` and all the automatic scripts it provides naturally)

Comment: You can then test that your localStorageMock's functions are used by doing something like `expect(localStorage.getItem).toBeCalledWith('token')` or `expect(localStorage.getItem.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)` inside of your tests if you wanted to make sure it was called. Check out https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Comment: for this I am getting an error -  jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy. Any ideas?

Comment: Won't this cause problems if you have multiple tests that use `localStorage`? Wouldn't you want to reset the spies after each test to prevent "spillover" into other tests?

Answer (score 40):

Unfortunately, the solutions that I've found here didn't work for me.

So I was looking at Jest GitHub issues and found this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6858)

The most upvoted solutions were these ones:

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem');

// or

Storage.prototype.getItem = jest.fn(() => 'bla');
```

Comment: My tests don't have `window` or `Storage` defined either. Maybe it's the older version of Jest I'm using.

Comment: Probably, it should be there with a recent jest- jsdom version.

Answer (score 17):

or you just take a mock package like this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-localstorage-mock

it handles not only the storage functionality but also allows you test if the store was actually called.

Answer (score 15):

A better alternative which handles `undefined` values (it doesn't have `toString()`) and returns `null` if value doesn't exist. Tested this with `react` v15, `redux` and `redux-auth-wrapper`

```
class LocalStorageMock {
  constructor() {
    this.store = {}
  }

  clear() {
    this.store = {}
  }

  getItem(key) {
    return this.store[key] || null
  }

  setItem(key, value) {
    this.store[key] = value
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    delete this.store[key]
  }
}

global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock
```

Comment: Thanks to Alexis Tyler for the idea to add `removeItem`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem

Comment: Believe null and undefined need to result in "null" and "undefined" (literal strings)

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking for a mock and not a stub, here is the solution I use:

```
export const localStorageMock = {
   getItem: jest.fn().mockImplementation(key => localStorageItems[key]),
   setItem: jest.fn().mockImplementation((key, value) => {
       localStorageItems[key] = value;
   }),
   clear: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
       localStorageItems = {};
   }),
   removeItem: jest.fn().mockImplementation((key) => {
       localStorageItems[key] = undefined;
   }),
};

export let localStorageItems = {}; // eslint-disable-line import/no-mutable-exports
```

I export the storage items for easy initialization. I.E. I can easily set it to an object

In the newer versions of Jest + JSDom it is not possible to set this, but the localstorage is already available and you can spy on it it like so:

```
const setItemSpy = jest.spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(window.localStorage), 'setItem');
```

Answer (score 13):

## For `Jest`, `React` & `TypeScript` users:

I created a `mockLocalStorage.ts`

```js
export const mockLocalStorage = () => {
  const setItemMock = jest.fn();
  const getItemMock = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    Storage.prototype.setItem = setItemMock;
    Storage.prototype.getItem = getItemMock;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    setItemMock.mockRestore();
    getItemMock.mockRestore();
  });

  return { setItemMock, getItemMock };
};
```

My component:

```js
export const Component = () => {
    const foo = localStorage.getItem('foo')
    localStorage.setItem('bar', 'true')
    return <h1>{foo}</h1>
}
```

then in my tests I use it like so:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { mockLocalStorage } from '../../test-utils';
import { Component } from './Component';

const { getItemMock, setItemMock } = mockLocalStorage();

it('fetches something from localStorage', () => {
    getItemMock.mockReturnValue('bar');
    render(<Component />);
    expect(getItemMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(getByText(/bar/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
});

it('expects something to be set in localStorage' () => {
    const value = "true"
    const key = "bar"
    render(<Component />);
    expect(setItemMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(key, value);
}
```

Comment: How would I use `setItemMock` in this solution? I am kinda confused and also new to testing/testing with jest.

Comment: @vveil I've added an example for consuming setItemMock as well.

Comment: This worked for me thank you !

Answer (score 9):

I found this solution from [github](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2098#issuecomment-260733457)

```
var localStorageMock = (function() {
  var store = {};

  return {
    getItem: function(key) {
        return store[key] || null;
    },
    setItem: function(key, value) {
        store[key] = value.toString();
    },
    clear: function() {
        store = {};
    }
  }; 
})();

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
 value: localStorageMock
});
```

You can insert this code in your setupTests and it should work fine.

I tested it in a project with typesctipt.

Comment: for me Object.defineProperty made the trick. Direct object assignment did not work. Thanks!

Comment: how to deal in service which get data from localStorage ?

Comment: you should use mock data instead of services for testing. In unit tests you should test  a single functionality.

Answer (score 7):

A bit more elegant solution using TypeScript and Jest.

```js
    interface Spies {
      [key: string]: jest.SpyInstance
    }
    
    describe('→ Local storage', () => {
    
      const spies: Spies = {}
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        ['setItem', 'getItem', 'clear'].forEach((fn: string) => {
          const mock = jest.fn(localStorage[fn])
          spies[fn] = jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, fn).mockImplementation(mock)
        })
      })
    
      afterEach(() => {
        Object.keys(spies).forEach((key: string) => spies[key].mockRestore())
      })
    
      test('→ setItem ...', async () => {
          localStorage.setItem( 'foo', 'bar' )
          expect(localStorage.getItem('foo')).toEqual('bar')
          expect(spies.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", {
  value: {
    getItem: jest.fn(),
    setItem: jest.fn(),
    removeItem: jest.fn(),
  },
});
```

or

```
jest.spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage), "getItem");
jest.spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage), "setItem");
```

Answer (score 6):

An update for 2022.

Jest@24+ has ability to mock local storage automatically. However, the dependency needed no longer ships with it by default.

`npm i -D jest-environment-jsdom`

You also need to change your Jest test mode:

```
// jest.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  ...
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  ...
};
```

Now localStorage will already be mocked for you.

Example:

```
// myStore.js
const saveLocally = (key, value) => {
  localStorage.setItem(key, value)
};
```

Test:

```
// myStore.spec.ts
import { saveLocally } from "./myStore.js"

it("saves key-value pair", () => {
  let key = "myKey";
  let value = "myValue";
  expect(localStorage.getItem(key)).toBe(null);
  saveLocally(key, value);
  expect(localStorage.getItem(key)).toBe(value);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this approach, to avoid mocking.

```
Storage.prototype.getItem = jest.fn(() => expectedPayload);
```

Comment: how to setup some service to load the data from localStorage ? Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63716411/setup-localstorage-for-testing-react-with-jest

Answer (score 3):

As @ck4 suggested [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/ed5c48c81b2139b4414810e1efe917e04c96ee8d/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#initializing-test-environment) has clear explanation for using `localStorage` in jest. However the mock functions were failing to execute any of the `localStorage` methods.

Below is the detailed example of my react component which make uses of abstract methods for writing and reading data,

```
//file: storage.js
const key = 'ABC';
export function readFromStore (){
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}
export function saveToStore (value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

export default { readFromStore, saveToStore };
```

*Error:*

```
TypeError: _setupLocalStorage2.default.setItem is not a function
```

**Fix:**
Add below mock function for jest (path: `.jest/mocks/setUpStore.js` )

```
let mockStorage = {};

module.exports = window.localStorage = {
  setItem: (key, val) => Object.assign(mockStorage, {[key]: val}),
  getItem: (key) => mockStorage[key],
  clear: () => mockStorage = {}
};
```

Snippet is referenced from [here](https://gist.github.com/sanusart/c1558845350cc8d8cafbe3c903d46afc)

Answer (score 3):

```
describe('getToken', () => {
    const Auth = new AuthService();
    const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Ik1yIEpvc2VwaCIsImlkIjoiNWQwYjk1Mzg2NTVhOTQ0ZjA0NjE5ZTA5IiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0cmV2X2pvc0Bob3RtYWlsLmNvbSIsInByb2ZpbGVVc2VybmFtZSI6Ii9tcmpvc2VwaCIsInByb2ZpbGVJbWFnZSI6Ii9Eb3Nlbi10LUdpci1sb29rLWN1dGUtbnVrZWNhdDMxNnMtMzExNzAwNDYtMTI4MC04MDAuanBnIiwiaWF0IjoxNTYyMzE4NDA0LCJleHAiOjE1OTM4NzYwMDR9.YwU15SqHMh1nO51eSa0YsOK-YLlaCx6ijceOKhZfQZc';
    beforeEach(() => {
        global.localStorage = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
            return {
                getItem: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(token)
            }
        });
    });
    it('should get the token from localStorage', () => {

        const result  = Auth.getToken();
        expect(result).toEqual(token);

    });
});
```

Create a mock and add it to the `global` object

Answer (score 3):

To do the same in the Typescript, do the following:

Setup a file with the following contents:

```
let localStorageMock = (function() {
  let store = new Map()
  return {

    getItem(key: string):string {
      return store.get(key);
    },

    setItem: function(key: string, value: string) {
      store.set(key, value);
    },

    clear: function() {
      store = new Map();
    },

    removeItem: function(key: string) {
        store.delete(key)
    }
  };
})();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: localStorageMock });
```

Then you add the following line to your package.json under your Jest configs

`"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile":"PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE",`

Or you import this file in your test case where you want to mock the localstorage.

Answer (score 3):

2021, typescript

```js
class LocalStorageMock {
  store: { [k: string]: string };
  length: number;

  constructor() {
    this.store = {};
    this.length = 0;
  }

  /**
   * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key
   * @returns
   */
  key = (idx: number): string => {
    const values = Object.values(this.store);
    return values[idx];
  };

  clear() {
    this.store = {};
  }

  getItem(key: string) {
    return this.store[key] || null;
  }

  setItem(key: string, value: string) {
    this.store[key] = String(value);
  }

  removeItem(key: string) {
    delete this.store[key];
  }
}

export default LocalStorageMock;
```

you can then use it with

```js
global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock();
```

Comment:  Nice work and thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests#comment117318024_41434763) by [Niket Pathak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4717533/niket-pathak),
starting jest@24 / [jsdom@11.12.0](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/c98e0f510625ef7adabfebeac80ab2fbda30493b/Changelog.md#11120) and above, `localStorage` is mocked automatically.

Comment: do you have any example for that ?

Comment: this! yes, I didn't have to do anything at all and I could just spyOn localStorage, just two minutes ago.

Comment: seems itts not, jest@28 does fail at localStorage places

Answer (score 3):

At least as of now, localStorage can be spied on easily on your jest tests, for example:

```
const spyRemoveItem = jest.spyOn(window.localStorage, 'removeItem')
```

And that's it. You can use your spy as you are used to.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and just one code line

`const setItem = jest.spyOn(Object.getPrototypeOf(localStorage), 'setItem');`

Answer (score 2):

Riffed off some other answers here to solve it for a project with Typescript. I created a LocalStorageMock like this:

```
export class LocalStorageMock {

    private store = {}

    clear() {
        this.store = {}
    }

    getItem(key: string) {
        return this.store[key] || null
    }

    setItem(key: string, value: string) {
        this.store[key] = value
    }

    removeItem(key: string) {
        delete this.store[key]
    }
}
```

Then I created a LocalStorageWrapper class that I use for all access to local storage in the app instead of directly accessing the global local storage variable. Made it easy to set the mock in the wrapper for tests.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is compatible for testing with stricter TypeScript, ESLint, TSLint, and Prettier config: `{ "proseWrap": "always", "semi": false, "singleQuote": true, "trailingComma": "es5" }`:

```
class LocalStorageMock {
  public store: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
  constructor() {
    this.store = {}
  }

  public clear() {
    this.store = {}
  }

  public getItem(key: string) {
    return this.store[key] || undefined
  }

  public setItem(key: string, value: string) {
    this.store[key] = value.toString()
  }

  public removeItem(key: string) {
    delete this.store[key]
  }
}
/* tslint:disable-next-line:no-any */
;(global as any).localStorage = new LocalStorageMock()
```

HT/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/51583401/101290 for how to update global.localStorage

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to mock localStorage - just use the jsdom environment so that your tests run in browser-like conditions.

In your jest.config.js,

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    testEnvironment: "jsdom"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**2022 December: Nx 14 with Angular 14 Jest.**
We have an `test-setup.ts` file in every app and libs folder. We setting local storage mock globaly.

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

Storage.prototype.getItem = jest.fn();
Storage.prototype.setItem = jest.fn();
Storage.prototype.removeItem = jest.fn();
```

Then `localStorage.service.spec.ts` file looking like this:

```
import { LocalStorageService } from './localstorage.service';

describe('LocalStorageService', () => {
    let localStorageService: LocalStorageService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        localStorageService = new LocalStorageService();
    });

    it('should set "identityKey" in localStorage', async () => {
        localStorageService.saveData('identityKey', '99');
        expect(window.localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(window.localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('identityKey', '99');
        expect(window.localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

it('should get "identityKey" from localStorage', async () => {
    localStorageService.getData('identityKey');
    expect(window.localStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(window.localStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('identityKey');
    expect(window.localStorage.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});

it('should remove "identityKey" from localStorage', async () => {
    localStorageService.removeData('identityKey');
    expect(window.localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(window.localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('identityKey');
            expect(window.localStorage.removeItem).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
    });
```

P.S. Sorry for bad indentation, this SatckOverflow window s*cks.

Answer (score 0):

none of the answers above worked for me. So after some digging this is what I  got to work. Credit goes to a few sources and other answers as well.

- https://www.codeblocq.com/2021/01/Jest-Mock-Local-Storage/
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6798#issuecomment-440988627
- https://gist.github.com/mayank23/7b994385eb030f1efb7075c4f1f6ac4c
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6798#issuecomment-514266034

My full gist: https://gist.github.com/ar-to/01fa07f2c03e7c1b2cfe6b8c612d4c6b

```js
/**
 * Build Local Storage object
 * @see https://www.codeblocq.com/2021/01/Jest-Mock-Local-Storage/ for source
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32911774/9270352 for source
 * @returns
 */
export const fakeLocalStorage = () => {
  let store: { [key: string]: string } = {}

  return {
    getItem: function (key: string) {
      return store[key] || null
    },
    setItem: function (key: string, value: string) {
      store[key] = value.toString()
    },
    removeItem: function (key: string) {
      delete store[key]
    },
    clear: function () {
      store = {}
    },
  }
}

/**
 * Mock window properties for testing
 * @see https://gist.github.com/mayank23/7b994385eb030f1efb7075c4f1f6ac4c for source
 * @see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6798#issuecomment-514266034 for sample implementation
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#properties for window properties
 * @param { string } property window property string but set to any due to some warnings
 * @param { Object } value for property
 *
 * @example
 *
 *  const testLS = {
 *    id: 5,
 *    name: 'My Test',
 *  }
 * mockWindowProperty('localStorage', fakeLocalStorage())
 * window.localStorage.setItem('currentPage', JSON.stringify(testLS))
 *
 */
const mockWindowProperty = (property: string | any, value: any) => {
  const { [property]: originalProperty } = window
  delete window[property]
  beforeAll(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, property, {
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      value,
    })
  })
  afterAll(() => {
    window[property] = originalProperty
  })
}

export default mockWindowProperty
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to set the localStorage value before I check it.

So what I did is

```
const data = { .......}

const setLocalStorageValue = (name: string, value: any) => {
  localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(value))
}



 describe('Check X class', () => {
  setLocalStorageValue('Xname', data)
  const xClass= new XClass()

  console.log(xClass.initiate()) ; // it will work 

  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> First: I created a file named localStorage.ts(localStorage.js)

```
class LocalStorageMock {
  store: Store;
  length: number;

  constructor() {
    this.store = {};
    this.length = 0;
  }

  key(n: number): any {
    if (typeof n === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error(
        "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'key' on 'Storage': 1 argument required, but only 0 present."
      );
    }

    if (n >= Object.keys(this.store).length) {
      return null;
    }

    return Object.keys(this.store)[n];
  }

  getItem(key: string): Store | null {
    if (!Object.keys(this.store).includes(key)) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.store[key];
  }

  setItem(key: string, value: any): undefined {
    if (typeof key === 'undefined' && typeof value === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error(
        "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present."
      );
    }

    if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error(
        "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present."
      );
    }

    if (!key) return undefined;

    this.store[key] = value.toString() || '';
    this.length = Object.keys(this.store).length;

    return undefined;
  }

  removeItem(key: string): undefined {
    if (typeof key === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error(
        "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeItem' on 'Storage': 1 argument required, but only 0 present."
      );
    }

    delete this.store[key];
    this.length = Object.keys(this.store).length;
    return undefined;
  }

  clear(): undefined {
    this.store = {};
    this.length = 0;

    return undefined;
  }
}

export const getLocalStorageMock = (): any => {
  return new LocalStorageMock();
};

global.localStorage = new LocalStorageMock();
```

Then create a test file named session.test.ts(session.test.js)

```
import { getLocalStorageMock } from '../localstorage';
describe('session storage', () => {
  let localStorage;
  beforeEach(() => {
    localStorage = getLocalStorageMock();
  });

  describe('getItem', () => {
    it('should return null if the item is undefined', () => {
      expect(localStorage.getItem('item')).toBeNull();
    });
    it("should return '' instead of null", () => {
      localStorage.setItem('item', '');
      expect(localStorage.getItem('item')).toBe('');
    });
    it('should return navid', () => {
      localStorage.setItem('item', 'navid');
      expect(localStorage.getItem('item')).toBe('navid');
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 and jest 29, you just have to add the jest-environment-jsdom package via

```
npm install --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom
```

and activate it in `package.json` via

```
"jest": { "testEnvironment": "jsdom"}
```

Now you can use `window.localStorage.setItem()` and `window.localStorage.getItem()` etc.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me,

```
delete global.localStorage;
global.localStorage = {
getItem: () => 
 }
```