# How to prevent "Property '...' does not exist on type 'Global'" with jsdom and typescript?

Tags: typescript, jsdom, typescript2.0

I try to convert an existing project to use Typescript and I have problems doing so with my testing setup.

I had a setup file for my tests that sets up jsdom so that all my DOM interacting code works during my tests. Using Typescript (ts-node with mocha) I always get errors like this:

```
Property 'window' does not exist on type 'Global'.
```

To prevent this I tried patching the NodeJS.Global interface like this:

```
declare namespace NodeJS{
  interface Global {
    document: Document;
    window: Window;
    navigator: Navigator;
  }
}
```

But this didn't change anything.

How do I enable those browser properties on the NodeJS global variable?

**Extras:**

This is my mocha `setup.ts`:

```
import { jsdom, changeURL } from 'jsdom';

const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = global.document.defaultView;
Object.keys(global.document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = global.document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};

changeURL(global.window, 'http://example.com/');
```

Comment: Can't be sure it's the right answer, but having gone through similar pain, it turns out that the file within which you extend the NodeJS.Global interface must be all lowercase, or typings will ignore it. Also, it can't have any import or export statements at the top - or it will be seen as a module rather than a typings file.

Comment: none of these answers seem to work, does anyone have an answer in 2018?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

## Original Answer To Avoid Error

Put this at the top of your typescript file

```
const globalAny:any = global;
```

Then use globalAny instead.

```
globalAny.document = jsdom('');
globalAny.window = global.document.defaultView;
```

## Updated Answer To Maintain Type Safety

If you want to keep your type safety, you can augment the existing `NodeJS.Global` type definition.

**You need to put your definition inside the global scope `declare global {...}`**

Keep in mind that the typescript `global` scope is not the same as the NodeJS interface `Global`, or the node `global property` called `global` of type `Global`...

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
       document: Document;
       window: Window;
       navigator: Navigator;
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Removing typings by casting `any` really goes against why Typescript is used in the first place. Infact if you're linting TSLint has an option specifically to prevent this: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any

Comment: @willsquire I updated the solution with a type-safe option.  The main reason this did not work for OP is included.

Comment: This declaration isn't compatible with eslint rule of not using namespaces. Look at my answer below for a more interesting approach.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with eslint, and rules are a matter of personal style.

Comment: ESLint rules are personal, true, but everyone nowadays typically will use all default rules as a base and disable or modify these than they're not comfortable with. My solution below covers all the cases and IMO it's more semantic therefore making the answer more complete.

Comment: it should be: `globalAny.window = globalAny.document.defaultView` otherwise again you get typescript error

Comment: Using the updated answer gives : `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'. Cannot find name 'Window'. Cannot find name 'Navigator'.`

Comment: @JeremyThille sounds like an issue including a library in your typescript config.  Those are all in the Dom library.

Answer (score 57):

In addition to other answers, you can also simply [cast](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html) `global` directly at the assignment site:

```
(global as any).myvar = myvar;
```

Comment: This is contradictory to typescript usage since it neutral type checking, the first principle usage of the typescript.

Comment: @ShahinGhasemi Really, I came to a point where I don't care. I am so tired of spending hours, and even entire days, just to make my apps compile and run. I used to develop and produce, now I spend more and more days solving typing errors, compilation issues and dependencies incompatinilities. I don't care if this goes against a paradigm or defeats a purpose. All I want at some point is my bloody app to compile and finally get some rest. This is the only solution that worked for me. All others just lead to new errors and issues.

Comment: @JeremyThille I really DO hear you, I think we are overcomplicating web development like if we were all trying to make the next huge application when maybe we are building a simple marketing site!

Answer (score 26):

I fixed this problem by doing this...

```
export interface Global {
  document: Document;
  window: Window;
}

declare var global: Global;
```

Comment: `export interface Global extends NodeJS.Global` if you want modify some but keep the rest of Global's properties, like `fetch`

Answer (score 21):

This is the right solution, not using Typescript's namespaces. It is also compatible with all eslint default rules:

```js
// Declare a type.
interface CustomNodeJsGlobal extends NodeJS.Global {
    myExtraGlobalVariable: number;
    // You can declare anything you need.
}
```

Use it:

```js
// Tell Typescript to use this type on the globally scoped `global` variable.
declare const global: CustomNodeJsGlobal;

function doSomething() {
  // Use it freely
  global.myExtraGlobalVariable = 5;
}

doSomething();
```

Comment: With the newest recommended @typescript-eslint rules, `eslint: error
@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access - Unsafe member access .Global on an any value.` may pop up. Solved by adding `type NJSGlobal = NodeJS.Global;` previously and extending `NJSGlobal`. Beyond that, this solution seems the best way to go.

Comment: Cleanest answer. People should be upvoting this one.

Answer (score 10):

Avoid typecasting `any`, it removes the purpose of typings. Instead install the type definitions needed (e.g. `yarn add --dev @types/jsdom @types/node`) and import to use:

```
import { DOMWindow, JSDOM } from 'jsdom'

interface Global extends NodeJS.Global {
  window: DOMWindow,
  document: Document,
  navigator: {
    userAgent: string
  }
}

const globalNode: Global = {
  window: window,
  document: window.document,
  navigator: {
    userAgent: 'node.js',
  },
  ...global
}
```

Comment: where do you put this?

Answer (score 5):

## How to declare something in `global`

1. Create `global` declaration file, for example: `src/types/index.d.ts`
2. Add your `global` declaration file to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* ... */
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types",
    ],
    /* ... */
  },
  /* ... */
}
```

### From [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)

> You can add declarations to the global scope from inside a module

So, for example, if you want to add something extra to the array interface, you need to do:

`observable.ts` (example)

```js
// observable.ts
export class Observable<T> {
  // ... still no implementation ...
}
```

`src/types/index.d.ts`

```js
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    toObservable(): Observable<T>;
  }
}
```

`someWhereInApp.ts`

```js
Array.prototype.toObservable = function () {
  // ...
};
```

### Declaring variables to access them from `global`

If you want to add a global variable to use as `global.myVariable` you need to do:

`src/types/index.d.ts`

```js
/* eslint-disable no-var */
declare global {
/*  ↓↓↓ "var" is important  */  
    var myVariable: string[];
}
/* eslint-enable no-var */
```

`someWhereInApp.ts`

```js
const { myVariable } = global
```

Answer (score 3):

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  export interface Global { window: any;
  }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers do very little to educate SO readers.  Please edit your answer to include some explanation. Your answer is in the moderation queue because it has been flagged as low-quality.

Comment: Tried your answer but global.window is still unresolved

Answer (score 1):

I was creating a nodeJS application with typescript and what fixed it for me was updating the `@types/node` in devDependencies to match the version I was using.

Comment: Updating the @types/node version to match the nodejs version helped me too.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method can be use extend the Typescript "Window" type

step 1: append Window object

```
interface Window {
    foo:string // any type of your foo property
}
```

step 2: declare

```
let foo = 'value of foo'
```

step 3: add to window object

```
window.foo
```

or

```
window.foo = foo
```

work for me...