# I want to know the count of how many times my after launch is getting executed in config file

Tags: typescript, protractor

In my config file beforeLaunch and afterLaunch is executing twice because failed scripts are again re-executing. I have used protractor flake to re-execute the files. I want to know the afterlanch and beforeLaunch count. Can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how the protractor flake npm package works but you could try using the [global variables](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/) node allows you to create.

**conf.js**

```
//Declare the variable
global.glbBeforeLaunchCounter = 0;
global.glbAfterLaunchCounter = 0;

exports.config = {
  beforeLaunch: function () {
    glbBeforeLaunchCounter = glbBeforeLaunchCounter + 1;

    //...
  },
  afterLaunch: function () {
    glbAfterLaunchCounter = glbAfterLaunchCounter + 1;

    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried doing that way, but when declaring it is showing me an error "[ts] Property 'glbAfterLaunchCounter' does not exist on type 'Global'. [2339]"

Comment: @akhila are you definitely declaring your global variable with a lowercase 'g'?

Comment: actually @akhila if you are using typescript [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743131/how-to-prevent-property-does-not-exist-on-type-global-with-jsdom-and-t) may be useful