# React unit test with Jest - issue on simulating localStorage

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I've an issue on unit testing a simple component (even more simplified here) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logout from '../auth/Logout';
import { logoutUser } from '../../actions/auth';

export default class Navbar extends Component {

  render() {
    const { dispatch, isAuthenticated } = this.props;

    if (isAuthenticated) {
      logStatus = <Logout onLogoutClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())} />;
    } else {
      logStatus = (
        <Link to="/login/">
          <Button>Login</Button>
        </Link>
      );
    }

    return (
      <AppBar>        
        {logStatus}
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}
```

in `import { logoutUser } from '../../actions/auth';`
I have a function removeItem on `localStorage`. I won't be using it for my test but that's where I have an error.

My test is :

```
test('Navbar test series', () => {
  //Enzyme testing
  it('show the login button', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navbar isAuthenticated={true} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Login)).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

I got :

```
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined      
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/axios/axios.js:8:15) [I don't know why this is here...]
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/actions/auth.js:89:38) [my logoutUser using localStorage is here ]
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/UI/Navbar.js:3:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/UI/Navbar.test.js:2:15)
```

Doing something like suggested here [How do I deal with localStorage in jest tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630)  :

```
var localStorageMock = (function () { [...]})();
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: localStorageMock });
```

is not helping.

What I don't get is that I'm not even calling `dispatch(logoutUser())` so why trying to access localStorage ?? Is the issue due to redux through dispatch ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

EDIT1 : 
Logout component :

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const Logout = props => (
  <Button onClick={() => props.onLogoutClick()}     color="secondary">LOGOUT</Button>
);

export default Logout;
```

And code from actions/auth.js and logoutUser() :

```
export function logoutUser() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(requestLogout());
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    dispatch(receiveLogout());
  };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with localStorage in jest tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests)

Comment: I don't think so, I've tried to "simulate" a localStorage using the post you links and it didn't change. I think the issue is more on why this logoutUser function is call in the first place ?

Comment: Can you post the code from `Logout` component?

Comment: Done, I've added Logout component. Very very simple.

Comment: I've found out that I have this error just by importing my component. Even without shallowing it... Strange, I'll dig that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your test files

```
global.localStorage = {
    getItem: () => undefined,
};

test('Navbar test series', () => {
  //Enzyme testing
  it('show the login button', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navbar isAuthenticated={true} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Login)).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Again, I've tried with this exact snippet to emulate localStorage https://stackoverflow.com/a/32911774/1565738 and it's not the issue here. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Done, I've added logoutUser() function from auth.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mocking `../../actions/auth` entirely for that test?

`jest.setMock('../../actions/auth', () => ({
    logoutUser: jest.fn()
}))`

Comment: I just tried, I'm still blocked on that localStorage error :) It was a good idea though !

Comment: A little off topic, but you should try [react-testing-library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library). Shallow rendering is a real pain.
In my tests I mock `localStorage` with
```global.localStorage = {
        setItem: jest.fn()
      };
``` 
and it does the trick. 
Hope you find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was in :

```
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/axios/axios.js:8:15) [I don't know why this is here...]
```

Where I've found a const using localstorage on runtime. Just put it in a condition and it solved the issue.

Thanks all for the effort, it was my mistake :-(

Comment: but why didn't the mock implementation get invoked? were you referring it by window.localstorage or something else?

Comment: because the `const token = localStorage.get[...]` was invoke at the root of my axios/axios.js and therefore call in the `import` chain. And so before the mock implementation of localStorage.

Comment: Even if I though I had tested once with the mock on first line but I guess I did it poorly...