# Jest mock third party object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I need some help on testing a third party object. Below is my code

```
//app.js
export const specialFunction = (offer) => {
   adobe.target.applyOffer({
       mbox: 'container',
       offer
   })
}


adobe.target.getOffer({
  mbox: 'container',
  success: (offer) => {
     specialFunction(offer);
  }
})
```

in my test file

```
//app.test.js
import { specialFunction } from './app';

beforeAll(() => {
  const adobe = {
     target: {
       getOffer: jest.fn(),
       applyOffer: jest.fn()
     }
  }
  window.adobe = adobe;
});
it('test function', () => {
    specialFunction({foo: 'bar'});
    expect(adobe.target.applyOffer).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        mbox: 'container',
        offer: {foo: 'bar'}
    });
})
```

but when I started to run it,`app.js` always reports 
`ReferenceError: adobe is not defined`
but if I change the `app.js` to be

```
typeof adobe !== 'undefined' && adobe.target.getOffer({
      mbox: 'container',
      success: (offer) => {
         specialFunction(offer);
      }
    })
```

then test passed, with the above `adobe.target.getOffer` not tested
so my question is, how to test `adobe.target.getOffer` part? and also why the test would pass? seems `window.adobe = adobe` is working for the test case

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the `at.js` library is being loaded without errors?

Comment: @DacreDenny  `window.adobe` is defined somewhere else, so I can use `adobe` directly without any error

Comment: this might be of use to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests#32911774 - in your case, instead of using this technique to mock `localstorage`, you would instead use it to mock `adobe`

Comment: @DacreDenny it does not work unfortunately. I will update the suggested code later

Answer (score 2):

In order to add **(mocked) methods** to the **global scope** you can append them on [Node's `global` object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) before your tests run. Like:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  const adobe = {
    target: {
       getOffer: jest.fn()
    }
  }
  global.adobe = adobe;
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I've updated the my code with more details. thanks