# Reactjs&Jest, Testing action that also changes localStorage

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

in my react + redux app I have an action that besides returning type and payload also changes localStorage like:

```
export const cancel = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("MyAppData");
  return { type: types.USER_CANCEL};
};
```

my test looks like:

```
test("user cancels", () => {
  const action = actions.cancel();
  expect(action).toEqual({
    type: types.USER_CANCEL
  });
});
```

writing no test for local storage I get

```
  ● user cancels

    ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

      33 |
      34 | export const cancel = () => {
    > 35 |   localStorage.removeItem("MyAppData");
         |   ^
      36 |   return { type: types.USER_CANCEL};
      37 | };
      38 |

      at Object.localStorage [as cancel] (src/actions/AllActions.js:35:3)
      at Object.cancel (__test__/actions/AllActions.test.js:56:26)
```

Therefore I made a mock for local storage

```
const mockStorage = {};
const localStorage = {
  setItem: (key, val) => Object.assign(mockStorage, { [key]: val }),
  getItem: key => mockStorage[key],
  removeItem: key => {delete mockStorage[key];console.log("Deleted: ", key);},
  clear: () => mockStorage
};
export default localStorage;
```

either importing this mock or using localStorage API, I still get same error

I got confused in how should I test that when I call `cancel()` also `localStorge.removeItem` is also called or the key and value is removed?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, there's no `window.localStorage` object inside Jest's test env. I'd recommend you to assign your mock to the `window` object. You can do it inside `beforeAll` method in your test file or globally for all your tests as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32911774/3921253).

After that, your code and tests will use it as native localStorage:

```
test("user cancels", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("MyAppData", "some_data");

  const action = actions.cancel();
  expect(action).toEqual({
    type: types.USER_CANCEL
  });

  expect(localStorage.getItem("MyAppData")).toBeNull();
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but when do not use the mock I get ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined in test, and when importing mock get same error from action itself

Comment: It may happen if your test environment is not `jsdom`. Because node.js doesn't have `localStorage`. Maybe [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) will help.

Comment: how should I recognize that? I have created with create-react-app CLI and all babel plugins for jest with .babelrc.

Comment: even if I do not write any test regarding local storage, and just check the return "type" again I get same error

Comment: Hi, again :) I have edited question with error log, if it helps

Comment: I think I figured it out. For some reason, there's no `window.localStorage` object inside test env. It's quite strange and I will investigate it tomorrow. For now, I can only suggest you assign your mock to the `window` object before calling your action creator. I will update my answer with and example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mocking localStorage, mock all its methods such as `removeItem` in order to see if it is invoked, you can use console.log in its mocked method.

Inside jest.config.js

Add

```
  setupFiles: [
    './jest.globals.js'
  ],
```

jest.globals.js

```
const mockStorage = {};
const localStorage = {
  setItem: (key, val) => Object.assign(mockStorage, {[key]: val}),
  getItem: key => mockStorage[key],
  removeItem: key => { delete mockStorage[key]; console.log('Deleted: ' + key); },
  clear: () => mockStorage,
};
global.localStorage = localStorage;
```

Now localStorage will be available globally throughout your tests.

To test:

```
test("user cancels", () => {
     const action = actions.cancel();
      expect(action).toEqual({
        type: types.USER_CANCEL
      });

      expect(localStorage.getItem("MyAppData")).toBeNull();
});
```

**Edit:**

As a final solution update your `jest.config.js` to use `testEnvironment: "jsdom"` this would use the localStorage of jsdom, you no longer will need to mock it.

Comment: `console.log` will not fail your test if the `removeItem` method is not called. You should rely only on assertions.

Comment: It answered on how to test if `localStorge.removeItem` was invoked, updating it for assertions as well.

Comment: But your answer can be understood as a suggestion to test the logic via console.log. Probably replacing "in order to test if it is invoked" with "in order to see if it is invoked" will fix this ambiguity.

Comment: Sure, that brings more clarity.

Comment: @Ayushya Thanks, but when I do not use mock I get ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined in the action file itself and when importing mock get the error in test file. where am I going wrong?

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi You are getting this error since localStorage is not available in global scope, you need to configure jest.config.js, add a file in setupFiles section, and set localStorage globally, updating my original answer

Comment: Thanks, I did so, but now I get-> TypeError: _localStorage2.default.getItem is not a function

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi Can you show the complete code for the same ?

Comment: @Ayushya yes, Thanks, this is the link https://github.com/AmirHMousavi/battleship-game.git

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I had a look on your repository, and found out the solution which will work for you.

in your jest.config.js, update testEnvironment to
  testEnvironment: "jsdom"

And remove all the mock for localStorage, with jsdom we'll no longer need mock for localStorage.
This passed all tests on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ayushya and @Oleksandr Kovpashko. I just found out if the app is created by CRA the whole approach is much more simpler. so uninstalled all packages and revert back to CRA defaults. and to the best of my knowledge, [only one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47897345/1624844,) was mentioning that. Also I was searching more at jest docs where the answer was in [CRA docs](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#srcsetuptestsjs-1)

so create `src/setupTests.js`

```
const localStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn(),
  setItem: jest.fn(),
  removeItem: jest.fn(),
  clear: jest.fn()
};
global.localStorage = localStorageMock;
```

by default the test script of CRA is

```
 "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
```

that can be changed to `node`