# Where does jest localStorage implementation come from?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I've created a small node app:

```
# package.json

{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0"
  }
}

# index.test.js

test('localStorage', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
    expect(localStorage.getItem('foo')).toBe('bar');
});
```

`npm test` runs without errors.

Searching on StackOverflow for "localStorage jest" leads to questions that deal with mocking `localStorage`; and I was under impression that Storage is a browser API that is not available in node.

So how come this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because by default jest uses [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) as its own [test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) (note that you can modify this behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

I think jest is switched to new version of [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/master/Changelog.md#11120) library