# Setup localStorage for testing React with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

How to deal with localStorage in React testing using jest.

I have been added to setupTest.js

```
const localStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn(),
  setItem: jest.fn(),
  removeItem: jest.fn(),
  clear: jest.fn(),
};

global.localStorage = localStorageMock;
```

Here's example of my service to get cache:

```
export default class Cache {
   getCache = () => {
     return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cache')));
   }
}
```

sample.test.js

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import Component from '../Component';

const cacheData = JSON.stringify(require('../__mock__/data.json'));

// Trying to mock the function causing error _Cache.default .....
jest.mock('./Cache', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      getCache: () => Promise.resolve(),
    }
  })
});

beforeAll(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('cache', cacheDate);
});

describe("<Component /> ", () => {
   it('set data to state', () => {
       const wrapper = mount(<Component />);
       wrapper.instance().getCache(); <-- my function in <Component /> to get data from cache service
       wrapper.update();

      console.log(wrapper.state()) <---- return null
   })
})
```

in `<Component />` componentDidMound cycle called the cache service to load the cache, and here I expecting the data getting from localStorage in the test. I have been trying another way to do this but nothing is working for me

Comment: I have been test for simple setItem and directly getitem in <Component /> data was added to localStorage. so maybe the problem is how to mocking the Cache service and make Component called it getCache function

Comment: *Trying to mock the function causing error _Cache.default* - what exactly is the error? `localStorage.setItem('cache', cacheDate)` - this doesn't help because you already stubbed it, it's a no-op. Either don't replace existing localStorage implementation (Jest JSDOM provides one), or mock it in a way that will work with yours, `localStorage.getItem.mockReturnValue(...)`.

Comment: yes the solution i am used is try to manual mocking the cache service and the data was exists. SOLVED