# ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined Jest error in Vue 2 Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, jestjs

I am getting below Jest error when testing my vue component.

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/threats.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

      3 | import variables from "@/shared/variables";
      4 | // get last routed items when user refresh the page
    > 5 | const lastRoute = localStorage.getItem(variables.LOCAL_STORAGE_ITEMS.LAST_ROUTE)
```

I am using Vue 2 with typescript for my application. Below is my state.ts file where I am using localStorage

**state.ts**

```
import variables from "@/shared/variables"

// get last routed items when user refresh the page
const lastRoute = localStorage.getItem(variables.LOCAL_STORAGE_ITEMS.LAST_ROUTE)
// Declare states
export class State {

    routeItems= lastRoute ? JSON.parse(lastRoute) : [{label:'Home', to:'/'}]
}
// exporting state
export const state: State = new State()
```

Spect file

```
  let wrapper; 
//   const $t = () => {}
    beforeEach(() => {
        
        wrapper = shallowMount(Biligule, {
          
        });
      });
    it("renders successfully", () => {
        
      expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)

    })
  }
```

jest.config.ts file

```
  module.exports = {
    preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    verbose: true,
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
    modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src', '<rootDir>/node_modules'],
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'ts', 'json', 'node', 'html'],
    transform: {
      '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
      '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
        'jest-transform-stub'
    },
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
      '/build/',
      '/config/',
      '/data/',
      '/dist/',
      '/node_modules/',
      '/test/',
      '/vendor/'
    ],
    globals: {
      'ts-jest': {
        tsConfig: 'tsconfig.json'
      },
      NODE_ENV: 'test'
    }
  }
```

Can you please tell me how to include localStorage for jest?

Comment: Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests). In a nutshell - you can consider to mock native browser apis for tests.

Comment: @udalmik - Hi, I already went through it and nothing works. I think it's old answer doesn't support anything it says for the current versions.