# How to mock localStorage for typescript unit tests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, jestjs, local-storage

Is there a way to mock localStorage with Jest?

I have tried many answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests) however, none seemed to work on typescript as I keep getting:

"**ReferenceError**: localStorage is not defined"

I also tried to make my own mock setup file:

```
export const localStorageMock = {
  getItem: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    data: ""
  })),

  removeItem: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    data: ""
  })),
};
```

And linking it like so:

```
jest.mock('localStorage', () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => localStorageMock);
});
```

Is there a way to do it? I only need to use getItem and removeItem for the methods I wish to test.

Comment: How is the `localStorage` being called in your target file under test?

Comment: It's called in the constructor of the tested class
```
class widget {
    data: string

    constructor() {
        this.data = localStorage.getItem('data')!
    }
...
}
```

Comment: The fact that you need to, while not *necessarily* wrong, is a **code smell**. You shouldn't mix I/O and logic, and I/O doesn't need unit tests. Ditto for mocking e.g. the `fetch` API.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock local storage like this:

```
const mockLocalStorage = (() => {
  let store = {} as Storage;

  return {
    getItem(key: string) {
      return store[key];
    },

    setItem(key: string, value: string) {
      store[key] = value;
    },

    removeItem(key: string) {
      delete store[key];
    },

    clear() {
      store = {} as Storage;
    },
  };
})();

export default mockLocalStorage;
```

Then in your test file you can set the mockLocalStorage as the local storage you want to use like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", {
  value: mockLocalStorage,
});
```

This may not be the best way of doing this, but it's a way that has worked for me in the past.

Comment: While it fixed the undefined localStorage problem. "ReferenceError: window is not defined" is now being displayed, and upon looking into it I can't seem to find a solution to it.

Comment: Where is it being displayed? What is your testing setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by defining a `localStorage` property on `windows` object.

**localStorageMock.ts :**

```
const localStorageMock = (() => {
  let store: { [key: string]: string } = {};

  return {
    getItem: (key: string) => store[key] || null,
    setItem: (key: string, value: string) => {
      store[key] = value.toString();
    }
  };
})();

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
  value: localStorageMock,
});
```

Now, in your test file, import the above file `localStorageMock.ts` and use Jest's function to mock the `localStorage` :

```
  import './localStorageMock.ts'; // Import the localStorage mock file

  it('should store value in localStorage', () => {
    // Use localStorage methods as usual
    localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue');
    expect(localStorage.getItem('myKey')).toBe('myValue');
  });
```